# Mix a 2x2 Rubik’s cube

Tags: optimization, rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

What is the minimum number of 1/4 turns of a solved 2x2 Rubik’s cube, such that no face will have two tiles of the same color?

(I do not have this puzzle’s solution.)

Comment: Is this an original puzzle?

Comment: @bobble It is, as far as I know. However, it does seem like the sort of thing someone else may have asked in the past, doesn’t it?

Comment: "As far as I know" is good enough for here :) The attribution requirement is meant to catch people who copy-paste from another source, or similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the shortest sequence I found:

> It can be done in **5** moves.
>  Using standard notation, the moves are: RDRDF.
>
>  Here is a graphical rundown of the moves: [image]

Comment: Do you have a proof for why less moves is impossible?

Comment: It’s been 24 hours, so I’m calling this solved (although I reserve the right to reconsider if someone comes along with a proof!). Great job! Also, thank you for the graphical rundown; I’m not fluent in the notation.

Comment: I went through all the non-equivalent 4-length sequences as best I can, and none of them works. But I'm not 100% sure I got them all, and it's not a very elegant proof